# Using awk to output lines between two patterns into different output files

Tags: file-io, awk

I have a file with many "start token lines" that starts with the word "MODEL", and many lines that end with an "end token line" that starts with the word "ENDMDL".

I would like to parse the file so that it grabs all lines starting from the "start token line" and ending at the "end token line" into a new output file.

In other words, if I ran this on a file with 100 of these "start token line" and "end token line", I would like to produce 100 files.

I have an awk command working:

```
 awk '/MODEL/ {flag=1;next} /ENDMDL/{flag=0} flag {print}' 1KZS.pdb > TEST
```

However, this command just prints all lines between MODEL-->ENDMDL into the *same* output file. But I would like each MODEL-->ENDMDL to output in a *new* output file.

How can my awk command be tweaked to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$ awk '/MODEL/{f=1;s="FILE"++i;next}/ENDMDL/{f=0;close(s)}f{print > s}' 1KZS.pdb
```

Comment: sudo_O. Thank you. In this input file I gave, it should make 20 output files. It correctly made the first 17 files. However, it then gave me an error "awk: TEST18 makes too many open files. input record number 5442, file 1KZS.pdb. source line number 1". Any idea what this error could mean?

Comment: It's mean exactly what is says `too many open files`. I have modified my answer to handle this by closing each file in the `/ENDMDL/` block.