# bash: separate blocks of lines between pattern x and y

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a similar question to this one [Sed/Awk - pull lines between pattern x and y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769411/sed-awk-pull-lines-between-pattern-x-and-y), however, in my case I want to output each block-of-lines to individual files (named after the first pattern).

Input example:

```
-- filename: query1.sql
-- sql comments goes here or else where
select * from table1
    where id=123; 
-- eof


-- filename: query2.sql
insert into table1
    (id, date) values (1, sysdate);
-- eof
```

I want the bash script to generate 2 files: `query1.sql` and `query2.sql` with the following content:

query1.sql:

```
-- sql comments goes here or else where
select * from table1
    where id=123;
```

query2.sql:

```
insert into table1
    (id, date) values (1, sysdate);
```

Thank you

Comment: here's another Q&A that might help you with saving the output to separate files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444738/using-awk-to-output-lines-between-two-patterns-into-different-output-files .. try it and add the code to question if you face difficulties in solving this problem

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am having a look now at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '/-- filename/{if(f)close(f); f=$3;next} !/eof/&&/./{print $0 >> f}' input
```

Brief explanation,

1. `-- filename{if(f)close(f); f=$3;next}`: locate the record contains filename, and assign it to `f`
2. `!/eof/&&/./{print $0 >> f}`: if following lines don't contain 'eof' neither empty, save it to the corresponding file.

Comment: This will run out of file handles after a while (commonly around 20 files on Linux IIRC) - you really should `if(f)close(f)` before starting a new file in the first block.

Comment: @tripleee, thanks for the tip, can you specify why it would `run out of file handles`?

Comment: The OS limits the number of file handles you can have open.  When you exceed this limit, your Awk script fails with an error message telling you you have too many files open. This isn't exactly hard to test yourself (hint: `awk '{ print >NR }' /some/big/file` in an empty directory)

Comment: Thanks for it, I'll take your suggestion to modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/-- filename: (\S+)/!d;s##/&/,/-- eof/{//d;w \1#p;s/.*/}/p;d' file |
sed -nf - file
```

Create a sed script from the input file and run it against the input file

N.B. Two lines are needed for each query as the program for the query must be surrounded by braces and the `w` command must end in a newline.

Comment: This is a nifty technique well worth knowing, but `sed -f -` isn't properly portable (nor is `sed -r`, nor does `sed -r` necessarily support `\S` even if it's available). Many people believe they have GNU `sed` when in fact even some Linux distros ship with a non-GNU `sed` implementation.

Comment: @tripleee to confirm the sed implementation try `sed --version` however I can only confirm this works with GNU sed ;)

Comment: @triplee wrt `well worth knowing` - I disagree as I can't imagine when you'd ever use this vs a simpler, clearer alternative in awk or shell.

Comment: @EdMorton I agree that I would not use `sed` for this particular task; but there are some problems which are elegantly solved by having `sed` generate a `sed` script.

Comment: @tripleee I think there's always a better alternative but I'm open to being proven wrong if you can think of an example.

Comment: @EdMorton I have a few moderately popular answers where I use this trick; but then I'm less of an Awk guru than you are. Here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7666384/874188

Comment: OK I posted an awk answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51423007/1745001. It'll run much faster than the sed scripts and won't fail given various possible contents of `LONG_ERROR_DESCRIPTION` such as `%` or `&` or `\1` or various possible error code values.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk to handle multiple open files for you:

```
awk '/^-- eof/{f=0} f{print > out} /^-- filename/{out=$3; f=1}' file
```

or with any awk:

```
awk '/^-- eof/{f=0} f{print > out} /^-- filename/{close(out); out=$3; f=1}' file
```